# O que significa o sinal de + no CSS?

Tags: css, css-seletores

Por exemplo:

```
.input__field--minoru:focus + .input__label--minoru::after {

}
```

Estou fazendo um efeito aqui, mas não estou entendendo esse sinal de `+` que tem no framework.

### Resultado Final

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $(".campo").on('click', function() {
     $(this).closest('div.form-group').addClass('active');
   });

 });
```

```css
 div.form-group {
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 700px;
   margin: auto;
   margin-top: 20px;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
 }
 div.active input[type="text"]:focus + label:after {
   animation: AnimShadow 0.3s forwards;
 }
 label {
   font-family: @pf_din_text;

font-size: 16px;
   color: #959ea4;
   display: block;
   padding-top: 10px;
   padding-left: 8px;
 }
 label:after {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: -1;
   width: 100%;
   height: 57px;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   color: rgba(199, 152, 157, 0.6);
 }
 input[type="text"] {
   width: 95%;
   border: none;
   font-family: "Verdana";
   font-size: 16px;
   color: #959ea4;
   background-color: #FFF;
   text-indent: 8px;
   height: 55px;
   outline: none;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px transparent;
   transition: all 0.3s ease;
 }
 input[type="text"]:focus {
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #FF9D12;
 }
body{
background-color: #f9f7f6;
}
 @keyframes AnimShadow {
   to {
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 50px;
     opacity: 0;
   }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" class="campo" />
  <label>Nome</label>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="campo" />
  <label>Email</label>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 Essa é um ótima pergunta @DeeSouza.

Comment: Obrigado. Eu estou fazendo um efeito no meu campo de texto e no framework está assim e não estava conseguindo implementar no site. E eu tinha certeza que era por causa que eu não tinha colocado essa instrução com o `+`. Porém, não sabia usar porquê não entendia o que fazia. Vou postar o que fiz.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Esse seletor `+` em CSS é chamado de  *Adjacent sibling selector*.

O sinal de `+` (Adjacent Selector) no CSS me lembra muito o método `siblings` do jQuery, que tem a finalidade de pegar um elemento irmão. No caso do CSS, representa um elemento subsequente (próximo) ao indicado anteriormente.

É útil, por exemplo, se você quer indicar que um `input`, quando estiver precedido por um `label`, tenha uma formatação diferente.

Veja o exemplo:

```css
.teste-a{
  background:red;
  color:white;
}

label+.teste-a{
  background:blue !important;
}
```

```html
<input class="teste-a">
<label>teste b</label>
<input class="teste-a">
```

Referências:

- [Mozilla - Adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)

Comment: Entendi! Top. Vou usar mais esse recurso, principalmente em formulários.

Answer (score 7):

Conforme a referência do [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp)

Atribui o estilo para o próximo elemento após o anterior

> Exemple: div + p
>
> Select and style every `<p>` element that are placed immediately after
> `<div>` elements: