# Pegar Elemento Específico CSS com Sinal de +

Tags: html, css

Minha pergunta tem relação com essa pergunta:

[O que significa o sinal de + no CSS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91175/o-que-significa-o-sinal-de-no-css)

Estou usando o sinal de + para fazer um efeito em um formulário que tenho.

Funciona, mas a questão é que meu formulário possui validação. Ou seja, quando clico no botão para submeter as informações do formulário é acrescentado no código uma `label.error`, com a mensagem de erro.

Daí o efeito no campo é perdido porquê o `ul.opcoes` não é mais o próximo campo quando aparece a `label.error`.

```
.select-area-field:focus + ul.opcoes{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Por isso minha pergunta é:

- Como fazer o CSS encontrar um elemento específico na árvore seguindo essas regras ?

### HTML

```
<div class="inline select-area">
    <input type="text" name="area" placeholder="Área Desejada" readonly="readonly" class="select-area-field"/>

    <!-- A Label aparece bem aqui -->

    <ul class="opcoes">
        @foreach($area as $item)
            <li data-id="{!! $item->id !!}">{!! $item->area !!}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
    <input type="hidden" name="cod-area" id="cod-area" />
</div>
```

Com **jQuery** se costuma fazer assim:

`$(document).find('div.wrapper');`

Comment: Na verdade eu tenho controle sobre a posição da `label.error`. Eu posso jogar tudo dentro de um container. Acabei de fazer isso e funcionou. Mas isso que perguntei já é possível com **CSS** ?

Comment: Não sei se esse é o melhor título para essa pergunta. :thinking:

Comment: O titulo ta bem ruim mesmo, ao ler o titulo pensei que você queria um seletor CSS para isso: `<span>+</span>` (um elemento com o conteúdo de um "+"). Hehe. Não sei muito bem como melhorar, mas o comando "+" no selector CSS recebe esse nome técnico: [**Adjacent sibling selectors**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors), talvez isso possa lhe ajudar. =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você pode fazer e considero o mais usual e correto nesse caso onde pode haver um elemento entre eles ou não, e no seu caso onde você conhece e tem controle sobre o elemento (`label.error`).

É adicionar a regra CSS a possibilidade de haver ou não o elemento `label.error` entre `.select-area-field:focus` e `ul.opcoes`, aplicando o estilo CSS para ambos os casos, a implementação poderia ser algo similar a isso:

```css
ul.opcoes {
  visibility: hidden;
}
label.error {
  color: red;
}

/* aqui está o segredo da solução */
.select-area-field:focus + ul.opcoes,
.select-area-field:focus + label.error + ul.opcoes {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline select-area">
  <input type="text" name="area" placeholder="Sem label error" readonly="readonly" class="select-area-field" />

  <!-- A Label aparece bem aqui -->

  <ul class="opcoes">
    <li>Opção 1</li>
    <li>Opção 2</li>
    <li>Opção 3</li>
  </ul>
  <input type="hidden" name="cod-area" />
</div>

<div class="inline select-area">
  <input type="text" name="area" placeholder="Com label error" readonly="readonly" class="select-area-field" />

  <!-- A Label aparece bem aqui -->
  <label class="error">label.error</label>

  <ul class="opcoes">
    <li>Opção 1</li>
    <li>Opção 2</li>
    <li>Opção 3</li>
  </ul>
  <input type="hidden" name="cod-area" />
</div>
```

[Exemplo disponível também no jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/fuL5ey6h/1)

Comment: Matou a pau, Vélho. Nem pensei nisso. Obrigado.