# Qual a diferença de se usar + e ~ no CSS

Tags: css

Existe um nome para esse tipo de seletor? fazem a mesma coisa? exemplo:

```
#mostrar:hover + #esconder {}
```

e

```
#mostrar:hover ~ #esconder {}
```

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91175/8063

Comment: [Como funcionam os seletores >, + , ~ no CSS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194920/como-funcionam-os-seletores-no-css)