# Porque a pseudo-classe :hover não está funcionando?

Tags: html

Eu tenho os seguintes elementos no meu html 
`<p id="p1">Passe o mouse sobre mim!</p>
 <p id="p2">Paragrafo</p>`

E no meu css tenho `

## p2

{
    display: none;
}

## p1:hover #p2

{
    display: block;
}`

Quando eu passo o mouse sobre o primeiro paragrafo o segundo não aparece porque ?

Answer (score 4):

A resposta do Anderson é a correta, mas só para te esclarecer mais, a forma como vc escreveu  `#p1:hover #p2` indica que vc está procurando o elemento `#p2` dentro do elemento `#p1`, ou seja, esse CSS indica que `#p1` é pai ou antepassado de `#p2`, mas no seu HTML eles são irmãos adjacentes, o `#p1` é irmão mais velho de `#p2`.

Acredito que isso não seja o que vc quer, mas seguindo a lógica do que disse acima, se `#p2` estiver dentro de `#p1`, o código vai funcionar. *O detalhe é que como vc não pode ter uma tag `<p>` dentro de outra. Então eu coloquei o `<p>` de dentro como um `<span>`, apenas como exemplo.*

```css
#p2 {
  display: none;
}

#p1:hover #p2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p id="p1">Passe o mouse sobre mim!
    <span id="p2">Paragrafo</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Um detalhe: em `#p1 #p2`, o elemento `#p1` não precisa ser necessariamente **pai** de `#p2`, mas sim ser antepassado de `#p2` em qualquer nível (pai, avô, bisavô, etc). Acho que utilizar o termo "pai" seria melhor apenas de fosse `#p1 > #p2`.

Comment: Oi era isso mesmo obrigado ajudou muito vlw, esqueci dos combinadores css

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss realmente, ele não precisa ser diretamente o pai, pode ser qualquer ancestral, editei ali para ficar mais claro, já que no usei o seletor `>`

Comment: @LeandroNascimento tmj meu jovem 

Answer (score 3):

Porque o seletor que você utilizou no CSS não está de acordo com a sua estrutura no HTML. Ao fazer `#p1:hover #p2` você estará selecionando o elemento `#p2` que **é descendente** do elemento `#p1`, porém no HTML os elementos são irmãos. Para selecionar elementos irmãos imediatamente em sequência, você deve usar o operador `+`, `#p1:hover + #p2`.

```css
#p2 {
  display: none;
}

#p1:hover + #p2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p id="p1">Passe o mouse sobre mim!</p>
<p id="p2">Paragrafo</p>
```

- [Como funcionam os seletores >, + , ~ no CSS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/194920/5878)
- [O que significa o sinal de + no CSS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91175/5878)

Comment: Oi obrigado cara!!! você me ajudou bastante mesmo obrigado mesmo de coração poxa passei quase uma semana tentando encontrar o problema e tinha esquecido dos combinadores css, mais valeu mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Faltou uma vírgula entre os dois ID's ali na declaração do CSS, o correto seria assim:

```
#p2 {
  display: none;
}

#p1:hover, #p2 {
  display: block;
}
```

Mas nesse caso vai depender um pouco do que você está tentando fazer, veja se assim te atende!

Comment: A solução do @AndersonCarlosWoss parece ser o que você está precisando, no caso da minha o hover funciona, mas apenas no #p1, no #p2, a característica fica sempre ativa.

Comment: Porém isso não fará que `#p2` apareça quando `#p1` possuir o *hover*, pois o elemento possuirá sempre `display: block` e nem faria sentido definí-lo como `none` inicialmente.

Comment: Concordo, não tinha me atentado ao `none` ali no começo! :-)